# Use function to write down variable name in Arduino

Tags: string, function, arduino

I have a script in Arduino that'll get a letter, and to make things as short a possible I'd like to use a string combined with another variable to get the variable name I need to fill in into the function.

I'd like this because I have a function `mySwitch.send(Int, 24)`. For the first `Int` variable I need to to send a number that is dependent on the letter I sent, and on the current value of `A_stat`, I defined these values in variables A_aan, A_uit, B_aan, B_uit, etc.

For example for the letter A I need to fill in the variable `A_aan` if `a_stat == 0`. If `a_stat == 1` it needs to fill in `A_off`.

For B I need to fill in the variable `B_aan` if `b_stat == 0`, and I need to fill in the variable name `B_uit` on the place of Int if `b_stat == 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of the variable vary at runtime, the only solution in my opinion is to use some functions.

For instance, if you want to get `#_aan`, where `#` is the value in a variable, you can use the following function:

```
int get_aan(char carat)
{
    switch(carat)
    {
        case 'A':
            return A_aan;
        case 'B':
            return B_aan;
        ...
    }
    return AN_INVALID_VALUE_YOU_DEFINE;
}
```

Remember to define an invalid value somewhere.

If you have to set that value, you can write a similar set function:

```
void set_aan(char carat, char value)
{
    switch(carat)
    {
        case 'A':
            A_aan = value;
            break;
        case 'B':
            B_aan = value;
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also include some flags. For instance, if you wanted to get variable `A_aan` when `A_stat = 0` and `A_off` when `A_stat != 0`, and repeat this for every variable, just modify the first function in:

```
int get_the_val(char carat)
{
    switch(carat)
    {
        case 'A':
            if (A_stat)
                return A_off;
            else
                return A_aan;
        case 'B':
            if (B_stat)
                return B_off;
            else
                return B_aan;
        ...
    }
    return AN_INVALID_VALUE_YOU_DEFINE;
}
```